# Bound properties not working

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I'm using TornadoFX 1.7.5 and I can't seem to get bound properties to work. I have the below ItemViewModels

```
class DynamicMenuViewModel : ItemViewModel<DynamicMenu>(DynamicMenu()) {
  val title = bind { item?.title?.toProperty() }
  val isBold = bind { item?.isBold?.toProperty() }
  val routes = bind { item?.routes?.toProperty() }
}
data class DynamicMenu(var title: String = "", var isBold: Boolean = false, var routes: MutableList<MenuRouteViewModel> = mutableListOf())

class MenuRouteViewModel : ItemViewModel<MenuRoute>(MenuRoute()) {
  val url = bind { item?.url?.toProperty() }
  val title = bind { item?.title?.toProperty() }
  val isBold = bind { item?.isBold?.toProperty() }
  val showNew = bind { item?.showNew?.toProperty() }
}
data class MenuRoute(var url: String = "", var title: String = "", var showNew: Boolean = false, var isBold: Boolean = false)
```

Which are bound like this:

```
//routesController.dynamicMenu is an instance of DynamicMenuViewModel()

textfield(property = routesController.dynamicMenu.title) {
  prefWidth = formWidth * .5
  gridpaneConstraints {
    columnRowIndex(0, 1)
    marginLeft = 10.0
    columnSpan = 2
    marginBottom = 20.0
  }
}

checkbox(property = routesController.dynamicMenu.isBold){
  gridpaneConstraints {
    columnRowIndex(2, 1)
    marginLeft = 15.0
    marginBottom = 20.0
  }
}
```

Then the following functions commit the models and prints them to the screen when I click a button:

```
  fun onClick(){
    commitModel()
    println(dynamicMenu.item.toString())
    dynamicMenu.item.routes.forEach {
      println(it.item.toString())
    }
  }

  fun commitModel(){
    dynamicMenu.item.routes.forEach {
      it.commit()
    }
    dynamicMenu.commit()
  }
```

The problem is that when I run the program and edit the textfields and checkboxes then click the button that runs `onClick()`, the backing item doesn't seem to be getting updated. So none of the updated values are printed to the console.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ViewModel can as you probably know only bind bidirectionally against JavaFX Properties. Your domain objects doesn't contain JavaFX properties, so you need to convert them. However, the `toProperty()` function you are using only operates on a value, and turns it into a Property. This property has no way of knowing about it's field owner, and hence cannot write back into the domain object.

Luckily, you can use the `observable` function to make your domain object properties writable as well:

`val url = bind { item?.observable(MenuRoute::url) }`

Since the `observable` function operates on a specific instance of a `MenuRoute` object, it now has enough information to write back into that instance when you `commit()` the model.

If you would consider changing the properties in your domain objects to be observable, you could write:

`val url = bind(MenuRoute::url)`

You can use the TornadoFX IDEA plugin inspection "Convert all properties to TornadoFX Properties" to automatically rework your properties. This would transform your `MenuRoute` object into:

```
class MenuRoute {
    val isBoldProperty = SimpleBooleanProperty(false)
    var isBold by isBoldProperty

    val showNewProperty = SimpleBooleanProperty(false)
    var showNew by showNewProperty

    val urlProperty = SimpleStringProperty("")
    var url by urlProperty

    val titleProperty = SimpleStringProperty("")
    var title by titleProperty
}
```

(You have to manually remove the `data` modifier on your class. Also beware that the current version of the plugin has a bug in the conversion function that would leave the old parameters - a new version will be released shortly).

If you don't want to do that for various reasons, I was just able to support that nice syntax even for mutable vars like you have, so from TornadoFX 1.7.6 you can use this syntax in your binding statements even if you don't want to change your data classes:

`val url = bind(MenuRoute::url)`